# Minimal code to create a Direct3D9 Device

Tags: visual-c++, directx, direct3d, direct3d9

This isn't for stable release code, I just need to get a windowed D3D9 device created in a C++ app from a HWND on my dev PC for testing something... it can default on loads of options.

I was trying to hack it together from an old D3D8 class I had but I'm getting D3DERR_INVALIDCALL.

Basically I have this now:

```
    HWND mHWnd = ...;
    LPDIRECT3D9 mpD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS md3dpp;
    ZeroMemory( &md3dpp, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS) );
    md3dpp.Windowed                 = true;
    md3dpp.SwapEffect               = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    md3dpp.BackBufferCount          = 1;
    md3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil   = 0;
    md3dpp.hDeviceWindow            = mHWnd;
    md3dpp.BackBufferWidth          = 0;
    md3dpp.BackBufferHeight         = 0;
    md3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = 0;
    md3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
    md3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    md3dpp.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
    md3dpp.MultiSampleQuality = 0;

    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 mpD3DDevice=0;
    HRESULT hr = mpD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,mHWnd,0,&md3dpp,&mpD3DDevice);
```

I figure some `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` options might be to blame - I don't care about back-buffers of z-buffers or stencils or AA, any old plain device is fine.

Have I copy-pasted together some incompatible flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 problem is that you need to set some Behaviour flags.

From the docs on [CreateDevice.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> BehaviorFlags [in]
>    DWORD
>    Combination of ***one* or more** options that control device creation. For more information, see D3DCREATE.

And from the [D3DCREATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs:

> D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, D3DCREATE_MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING, and D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING are mutually exclusive flags. **At least one** of these vertex processing flags must be specified when calling CreateDevice.

Try:

```
HRESULT hr = mpD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,mHWnd,D3DCREATE_MIXED_VERTEXPROCESSING,&md3dpp,&mpD3DDevice);
```

Comment: Doh! That's what comes from brainless code-pasting. It works as expected now.

Comment: @John: Hehehe, its easy to miss :)